# Does Apache's SetEnv directive work if not in CGI mode?

Tags: apache, setenv

Quoted from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv):

> Sets an internal environment variable, which is then available to
>   Apache HTTP Server modules, and passed on to CGI scripts and SSI
>   pages.

Does it work for mod_php or mod_perl that's embedded into Apache directly?

Answer (score 0):

For perl, use PerlSetEnv.

In the Apache config:

```
PerlSetEnv  VAR1 value
PerlSetEnv  VAR2 "value with spaces"
```

Then, in the perl code, access as usual:

```
print STDERR $ENV{VAR1}, "\n";
```